# What is SIM Toolkit and how do I remove it?

Tags: stock-android

I've had this app (SIM Toolkit) since forever and can't seem to find a way to remove it.

[image]
<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

Answer (score 8):

SIM Toolkit brings up a list of things like horoscopes, music videos, chat etc. It depends on your service provider and you're not really missing much by not being able to use it! You can't delete the app if your phone isn't rooted.

You can remove it if you're *S-OFF*/using a *custom ROM*. Just remove stk.apk from `/system/app` directory

But in my opinion leave it, don't bother removing it because it's really small app.

Comment: Very good Reason to remove it: STK Attacks.

Comment: Unless you're from Estonia and use mobile ID service (a way to authenticate yourself and sign documents electronically using a SIM card with the signing app and certificates as the key). In this case, that app is actually useful and required.

Comment: Bad advice, sim toolkits not only are annoying, but also allows carriers to exploit interruptions which may make you subscribe to paid services by accident when they show popups at random times. There is no need to root (at least not anymore) or use a custom rom, you can remove it with developer options, although I do think this is still very poor on giving user a choice. https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/181557/how-to-remove-the-sim-toolkit-from-my-phone-without-root-or-flashing-any-rom

Answer (score 1):

You should let it be.

If you use a launcher such as APEX, you can hide the icon from the app drawer.

Comment: Why let it be?‌ Whats it's its usage and purpose? In my experience I found it much useless and was causing my smartphone to get unwanted advertising confirmation dialogs rapidly (there was a security bug from sim toolkit) and when I removed it everything goes very well without problem.