# How do I remove SIM Toolkit app?

Tags: uninstallation, system-apps

About 2 months ago or so, I upgraded my SIM to 4G and I realized after the upgrade there's a SIM Toolkit icon on my home screen and I'm about to move it at least at my Tool folder.

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click to enlarge)</sup>

Apparently, when I turn off my Airplane Mode (turn on my mobile network), I saw the SIM Toolkit settings again and I'm about to remove/disable it. I saw that I couldn't disable it, only Force Stopping it. But when I turn on my Mobile Network again, it appeared again.

Please help me how to remove it, I also couldn't hide it. Thanks

Comment: What device is this? Because this application is common in many stock phones and custom ROMs installed in the system, meaning you can't remove it. It is in my stock Moto X Pure Edition and Moto G devices, in fact all the phones I checked in our house have it installed. To remove it you would need root access to your device and a tool like Titanium Backup or Root Explorer

Comment: See https://android.stackexchange.com/q/96758/96277. You might be better off with a custom home launcher instead of unnecessary messing with that app. However, if you do want to remove that app, which you cannot without rooting the device, consider [hiding](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/141528/96277) the app.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy.

1. First, you need to root your phone.
2. Take a backup from the SIM Toolkit (just in case). You can find a backup app in Google Play Store. After installing this app, you should choose system app to find SIM Toolkit.
3. Find a root app uninstaller (e.g. [Root Uninstaller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rootuninstaller.free)) and remove SIM Toolkit.